# javascript Delete from array between 2 indices

Tags: javascript

With an array of: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

I would like to delete between 2 indices such as `2` and `4` to produce `[1, 2, null, null, 5, 6]`. What's the easiest way to do this?

Hopefully better than this:

```
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
let i = 2;
const rangeEnd = 9;
while (i < rangeEnd) {
  delete array[i];
  i++;
}

console.log(array)
```

Comment: `array[2] = null; array[3] = null` ... ?  That's not a "delete"

Comment: @Taplar I think those are 1 off, and it should be generalized for any 2 indexes.

Comment: Ok, but you understand the concept and can elaborate upon it to fit your need.  I'm putting it as a comment because I'm not sure why this is a hard thing to come up with.  If you are talking about making it dynamic, then you are simply talking about implementing it with a loop, using variables.

Comment: @Taplar I was wondering if there's a native API that I'm not familiar with that can do it easily instead of writing a loop. I called it delete because that's what you get when you `delete array[2]`. If the loop is the best way then that's fine, that's the answer. I just had a feeling there was a better way.

Comment: If you want to actually remove the array elements, then you are talking about a usage of the `splice()` method

Comment: @Taplar thanks but I'd like to keep the indices the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use some native API you can actually do this with `splice()`. Otherwise, you should iterate a for loop through your array and change the value in each iteration.

Here is an example of how it would be done:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

array.splice(3, 2, null, null) // the First element is beginning index and the second is count one will indicate how many indexes you need to traverse from the first one, then you should provide replace element for each of them.

console.log(array)
```

**Note:** For more info about it you can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

There is a possible workaround for large scale replacement, so I will give it a touch here:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var anotherArr = Array(2).fill(null); // or you can simply define [null, null, ...]

Array.prototype.splice.apply(arr, [3, anotherArr.length].concat(anotherArr));

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thanks, is that generalizable if the range is very large?

Comment: @Harry Yea but the only problem with it is, when your provided indexes get out of range of actual array it will automatically append new items to your array.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not feeling the provide replacement element part though.

Comment: @Harry No problem, there is something that can come handy, check the update and share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

As you mean the range (2, 4] so you can follow this:
**The range is:** lower limit exclusive and the upper limit inclusive.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

const deleteRange = (arr, f, t) => {
    return arr.map((item, i) => {
 if (i + 1 > f && i + 1 <= t) {
     return null;
 }
 return item;
    })
}

console.log(deleteRange(arr, 2, 4));
```